# NSLogger, how to show the instance information of the Log caller in log

Tags: ios, logging

I use [NSLoger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger/wiki/NSLogger-API) in iOS app, it great, it can show function name, file line, just I also want show the instance of the class information.

eg: class A methods is 'doAction', a instance : A* a = [A alloc];

```
  in method 'doAction':
  {
        NSLog(@"out this instance information, do not need repeat set the argument [%@]",self );
  }
```

I meaning is that I do not need define the format and the 'self' argument in every NSLog statement....

how to do it ? may I explain clearly and need your help thanks.

so... then I try to add some code as follows:

```
 void LogMessageMe( const char *filename, int lineNumber, const char *functionName,id  target, int level, NSString *format, ...)
{
    NSString* strTarget = [target description];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    LogMessageTo_internal(NULL,  filename, lineNumber,  functionName, strTarget, level, format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

and

```
#define NSLogMe(...)                      LogMessageMe( __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, self, 0, __VA_ARGS__)
```

the call code as follows:

```
 NSLogMe(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
```

then output log:

```
  <AppDelegate: 0x906e100> | Main thread | didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

that is really what I want to see... since in a app, many instance was create but that is the same class... if no the identify number, it is hard to trace the target instance ....

but still a issue...

IDE report warning message about the statement:

```
NSLogMe(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
```

*"Implicit declaration of function ‘LogMessageMe’ is invalid in C99"*

it seem small issue... anyone help ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `%p` specifier in NSLog statements to output the value of a pointer:

```
NSLogMe(@"Called from %@ instance %p", [self class], self);
```

These are standard `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]` specifiers. For a complete list, see the documentation for [string format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).

Comment: thanks fplillet....  that is a way,but every statement includes the format seem too trouble, that is why I want the logger can auto output the 'self' value ...

Answer (score 0):

The warning has nothing to do with NSLogger.

You need to define the macro `NSLogMe` in a place where the function signature `LogMessageMe` is visible.

And if you declare `LogMessageMe` outside of `LoggerClient` then you need to make `LogMessageTo_internal` public (now it isn't, as its name indicates).